# Posting minutiae byte array from applet to server

Tags: java, grails, applet, http-post, fingerprint

In Grails web application, I am trying to post minutiae (finger print) byte array from applet to server using rest API.

This what i tried so for

```
private String post(String purl,String customerId, byte[] regMin1,byte[] regMin2) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();
    parameters.append("customerId=");
    parameters.append(customerId);
    parameters.append("&regMin1=");
    parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(new String(regMin1),"UTF-8"));
    parameters.append("&regMin2=");
    parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(new String(regMin2),"UTF-8"));
    URL url = new URL(purl); 
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(parameters.toString().getBytes().length));

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes(parameters.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String aux = "";

    while ((aux = in.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(aux);
    }
    in.close();
    connection.disconnect();
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I can post regMin1, regMin2 successfully but fingerprint verification always failing. I doubt, am i posting correctly.

Comment: why don't you use apache's `HttpClient`? with that you could assemble a POST request w/o such complexities

Comment: @injecteer Ok, i just started that. Thanks.

Comment: @Viswa Can you post your grails code? I want to see how you took the data from there.

Comment: @Ramsharan Thanks for the interest.. I got it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a very bad idea to me:

```
parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(new String(regMin1),"UTF-8"));
...
parameters.append(URLEncoder.encode(new String(regMin2),"UTF-8"));
```

If `regMin1` and `regMin2` aren't *actually* UTF-8 text (and my guess is that they're not) you'll almost certainly be losing data here.

*Don't treat arbitrary binary data as if it's encoded text.*

Instead, convert `regMin1` and `regMin2` to base64 - that way you'll end up with ASCII characters which you can then decode on the server to definitely get the original binary data. You can use a URL-safe version of base64 to avoid having to worry about further encoding the result.

There's a [good public domain base64 library](http://iharder.net/base64) you can use for this if you don't have anything else to hand. So for example:

```
parameters.append("&regMin1=")
          .append(Base64.encodeBytes(regMin1, Base64.URL_SAFE))
          .append("&regMin2=")
          .append(Base64.encodeBytes(regMin2, Base64.URL_SAFE));
```

Note that you'd want to decode with the `URL_SAFE` option as well - don't just try to decode it as "normal" base64 data.

(You might still want to convert this to a POST request, and you'd definitely have an easier time if you could use a better HTTP library, but they're slightly separate concerns.)

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet.. Yes, I am trying with Base64 based on your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894723/encode-byte-as-string).. URL_SAFE is useful info.. Wow Jon Skeet answered my question..

Comment: @Viswa: So, is it working now? Anything else you need to know about?

Comment: Yes it is.. Thanks @Jon Skeet

Comment: One out of topic question "Which book/source is good for learning java net & Collections and threading concepts ?"

Comment: @Viswa: I don't have any particular recommendations on that front, but note that Java 8 has provided a lot of new options for data handling using Streams.